# difference between ionic and android sdk

Tags: java, android, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I want to build an android app, and I have read, but very little about ionic which is also used to create mobile applications. I have worked on android more, and want to know what is the difference between both ? sorry for asking a general question, but I could not understand the difference between the purpose served by both Android SDK (Java) and ionic (html, css, angular js).

Comment: Did you ever heard `native application` vs `hybrid application` ? Actually writing code in java by using android tool is called `native app` which will run only android environment. Another is `hybrid` app which usually code in `js` + `HTML CSS` runs on every environemnt. There are many articles you will get of that. For the `hybrid` app developement, `ionic` is most usable in the race.

Comment: Check Out    **https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-HTML5-Native-and-a-Hybrid-app-Which-is-better**

Comment: ionic(Hybrid Apps) will run in multiple platform like android,ios etc,but apps like Android (Native Apps) Apps will only run in single(native) platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First don't compare Ionic with Android. Ionic is an Hybrid/Cross Platform Framework, based on Apache Cordova.

If you want develop the Application only for Android devices you can opt for Native Android. If your target is both Android and iOS go ahead with Ionic.

Ionic uses AngularJS and you need Javascript, HTML5 and CSS knowledge.  Where Android native coding is based on Java.